# $wpdb->get_results shows and empty array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get some data form wordpress db and it somehow gives me back an empty array.
When I am trying this query below I receive the whole details and it is working perfectly.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta");
```

But when trying this query below it gives me back an empty array like this: **array(0){}**

```
$user_data = get_userdata($current_user_id); // get current user data by id 
$user_url = $user_data->user_url; // get current user url
$user_url = substr($user_url, 6);

global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_value = %s", $user_url);
echo $query;

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
var_dump($results);
```

Please help me, I am trying to figure it out without any success...

Comment: why `$user_url = substr($user_url, 6);` ?

Comment: Because I want to remove the http:/

Comment: could you try `LIKE` instead of `=` in your query?

Comment: Tried.. no success.
Still getting and empty array()

Answer (score 0):

`user_url` is a column in the `wp_users` table. It's not in the metadata table.

Comment: It is not the problem. 
$user_url variable equals to what I need to pass.
When I am using echo $query it looks like this: 
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = '/register/?utm_source=referral&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=jan'